# How do I Pass a Nid to a webform and create a token for a different field on that node?

Tags: webforms, entities, tokens

**Use Case**:
I have a content type called "Team" which contains an email address.  I have a view that creates a link to create a webform to contact the Team member and prepopulate the email address in a hidden field.

The Team member does not have a user profile.
I do not want to pass the email to the webform url since that would expose it.
I do understand how to pass a value to a webform.
I want to avoid maintaining a custom module.

**Issue**:
I hoped I could pass the Nid of the content entity and use an entity token to "lookup" the email as a default, hidden field and use that to generate the webform.  I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental (please don't down the question ...)

**Question**:
If I can get a token such as [current-page:query:nid] from the URL, how do I use that to get the email field [node:field-email] for say Nid=5?  Should token chaining something like [current-page:query:nid:field-email] work?  I can't seem to find good documentation on token reference chaining - that would be very helpful.

Installed D7.33, Token, Entity Token, Entity Reference.

I have viewed several similar cases that do not apply:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95774/how-to-pass-a-token-to-webform-from-a-node-relationship
[referencing/linking to an entityform and passing nid/other field information through the URL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54710/referencing-linking-to-an-entityform-and-passing-nid-other-field-information-thr)
[Creating a token for the image field file path with node reference nid](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/creating-a-token-for-the-image-field-file-path-with-node-reference-nid)
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95774/how-to-pass-a-token-to-webform-from-a-node-relationship

**Note**: I found this module, but not sure if it is necessary: https://www.drupal.org/project/aet

Comment: Can you sidestep the problem by inserting the email to a 'private' field and hence not 'expose' it?

Comment: yes, but it will be exposed in the URL and lower corner of the browser.  I'm ok with obfuscation but that is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1):

How many teams are there?

If not too many, you could set up categories in your site contact form in `admin/structure/contact` that represent each team then pass the team name to the contact form, thus not exposing the email address.

Comment: nice idea but will be a lot to manage.  perhaps i could set up a rule to create a term for each contact but it requires maintaining a lot.  was hoping there was a simple way.